# How do you change the color of text when you click a card in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you change the color of text when you click a clickable card?

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => , // here
    child: Card(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(title),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a default color. Then `setState` onTap of `GestureDetector` like this:

```
         Color _color = Colors.red;

// ...

          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _color = Colors.black;
                  });
                }, // here
                child: Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "title",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: _color,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

add a variable `bool tapped = true;` and in the `onTap: () { tapped = !tapped; setstate({}); }`

and add `Text(title,style: TextStyle(color: tapped ? Colors.green ? Colors.grey),),